# How do I use the return value of a function in another one?

Tags: c, function, return, return-value, scanf

This is my `main.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
  printHeadline();
  function1();
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    menu();
    if (menu() == 1) {
      return 0;
    } else if (menu() == 2) {
      int p1 = 1, p2 = 2;
      ReadNumbers(&p1, &p2);
    } else if (menu() == 3) {
      int p1 = 1, p2 = 2;
      add(&p1, &p2);
    } else if (menu() == 4) {
      int p1 = 1, p2 = 2;
      subtract(&p1, &p2);
    } else if (menu() == 5) {
      int p1 = 1, p2 = 2;
      divide(&p1, &p2);
    } else if (menu() == 6) {
      int p1 = 1, p2 = 2;
      multiply(&p1, &p2);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my `functions.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add(int x1, int x2) {
  return x1 + x2;
}

int subtract(int x1, int x2) {
  return x1 - x2;
}

float divide(int x1, int x2) {
  return x1 / x2;
}

int multiply(int x1, int x2) {
  return x1 * x2;
}

void ReadNumbers(int *p1, int *p2) {
  int x1;
  int x2;
  printf("Integer 1:");
  scanf("%d", &x1);

  printf("Integer 2:");
  scanf("%d", &x2);

  *p1 = x1;
  *p2 = x2;
}

int menu() {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("\n\nChoose from menu:\n1. Exit\n2. Read two numbers\n3. Add\n4. Subtract\n5.     Divide\n6. Multiply\n\nYour choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &menu);

    if (menu == 1 || menu == 2 || menu == 3 || menu == 4 || menu == 5 || menu == 6)
      return menu;
    else
      ++i;
    fflush(stdin);
  }
}
```

At the moment the program is crashing when choosing a number in the menu. I tried debugging and it pointed to this line:

```
scanf("%d", &menu);
```

Not sure where to go or what to do next. I tried a bunch of stuff but I'm relatively new to C.

Comment: Please try reducing your code to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

In your ReadNumbers function you assign the adresses of two local variables to your pointer arguments (int x1, int x2). These variables go out of scope as soon as the function returns and the adresses will be invalid yielding undefined behaviour.
Try working with your pointer arguments instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should code e.g.

```
        int p1 = 1, p2 = 2;
        float q = divide(p1, p2);
```

then use `q` in the same block. BTW, function calls can be nested, e.g. like in 
 `q = divide(p1, substract(p1, p2));`

You need to read more about [programming in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/).

Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler, e.g. by compiling with:

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -o yourprog
```

Then use `gdb` -or some other debugger- (e.g. as `gdb ./yourprog`)